# User or Role authorization using AuthorizeAttribute in .Net Core

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm using below code working fine in ASP.Net MVC. I need this code is convert to **Dot net Core**. But here **httpcontextbase** is not get as parameter and **RedirectToRouteResult, RouteValueDictionary**  are throw an error. Please give the solution for MVC to .Net core. Thanks In Advance.

```
  public class RoleAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    private readonly string[] permissionRoles;
    private users user = null;
    private string currentRole = null;

    public RoleAuthorizeAttribute(params string[] roles)
    {
        this.permissionRoles = roles;
    }

    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        user = userHandler.GetLoginUserRecord();
        currentRole = userHandler.GetLoginUserRole();
        bool authorize = false;

        if (user != null)
            authorize =  permissionRoles.Contains(currentRole);

        return authorize;
    }

    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext actionContext)
    {
        if (user == null)
        {
            actionContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary { { "action", "Login" }, { "controller", "Account" } });
        }
        else if (permissionRoles.Contains(currentRole) == false)
        {
            actionContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary { { "action", "Logout" }, { "controller", "Account" } });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi. Perhaps if you show us what you have tried, then people would be more keen to help you out. Demanding a complete re-write of your code, it's not something people here will do for you, unless you at least show some effort.

Comment: Why are you even doing this over just simply: `[Authorize(Roles = "Foo")]`?

Comment: In ASP.NET Core ,When an identity is created it may belong to one or more roles . You could use Role-based authorization which checks are declarative—the developer embeds them within their code, against a controller or an action within a controller, specifying roles which the current user must be a member of to access the requested resource. Reference :https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/roles?view=aspnetcore-2.2